# SAX based parser for android PLIST format data

Tags: android

I am using plist as data for my android application since the iphone also supports the same.

I have written a parser which parsers character by character, but it takes a really long time to run my app. I think a sax parser would solve this, do you have any suggestions?

Also I have [this](https://github.com/CarlLee/android-plist-parser/tree/98d4d3bfc2deb5c4cf413d5d359ddde4e2d4d0b8/android-plist-parser-app) link which says its a sax based parser for plist android but i cant figure out a way to run this in eclipse if any one knows please help out.

Thanks 
Deepesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with this app right now.
Everything is straight forward. Download this
https://github.com/CarlLee/android-plist-parser/downloads

There are 2 projects there
android-plist-parser-app - objects and parsing logic

android-plist-parser-test - testing app.

Start to discover from testing app and you will find out how it works.